# Animate diurnal movement of the sun for an evelation map

Tags: animation, light, keyframes

I am really sorry for this super basic question. I am completely new to blender. And while I should do many other things I really felt in love playing around with it.
My very simple question is now the following:

I created a hillshade using an elevation map in an image texture. Now I'd like to animate the movement of the sun in one day. So I just have one plane, that gets displaced, and I'd like to cast the shadows depending on the location of the sun.

I don't really know where to start looking for hints on how to start animating certain parameters (the position of the sun in this case), so I just asked here:)

Comment: There used to be a Sun Position add-on shipped with blender to do exactly that with handy parameters. What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using version 2.9 and I found that plugin too:) I also can get the sun moving, but my camera also moves with it:/ I'd like to have it fixed over my elevation map